running Strapi with Docker seems to run in production env
Sorry for the bad explaination. I have a problem when I try to run Strapi in dev mode with Docker. If I run the app with Docker, the interface misses the content-type builder and all the Development options.
It happens specifically when I run the MySQL container with Docker. If I run the application locally, there is no problem.
Here is my Docker files :
Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine3.18
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatibility
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm bash vips-dev
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node
RUN ["yarn", "build"]
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "develop"]

Docker-compose.yml:
version: "3"
services:
  heritage-cms:
    container_name: heritage-cms
    build: .
    image: heritage-cms:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: heritage-cmsDB
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ./config:/opt/app/config
      - ./src:/opt/app/src
      - ./package.json:/opt/package.json
      - ./yarn.lock:/opt/yarn.lock

      - ./.env:/opt/app/.env
      - ./public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    networks:
      - heritage-cms
    depends_on:
      - heritage-cmsDB

  heritage-cmsDB:
    container_name: heritage-cmsDB
    platform: linux/amd64 #for platform error on Apple M1 chips
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      # MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/heritage_prod.sql
      - heritage-cms-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - heritage-cms

  heritage-cmsAdminer:
    container_name: heritage-cmsAdminer
    image: adminer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=heritage-cmsDB
    networks:
      - heritage-cms
    depends_on:
      - heritage-cmsDB

volumes:
  heritage-cms-data:

networks:
  heritage-cms:
    name: Heritage-cms
    driver: bridge

I also add the strapi database.js file :
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "mysql",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT"),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
      ssl: env.bool("DATABASE_SSL", false),
    },
  },
});

I don't what else to provide to give more informations
Thank you
